# Returning Multiples of SUM when joining two tables

Tags: sql-server-2005, join, sum

When I join these two tables the sum results are multiples of the number of rows in the tables being queried. For instance, sum(jle.Unit Price) should be  $834,485.00.  However, it returns a value of $7760710.50. It is summing the lines from that table 31 times, the same number, minus one, of rows in the jpl table.  The same for the sum on jpl.[Total Price].  Returning 3 times (for the three rows in jle table) than the result should be.  What am I doing wrong.  I want to add this to a query that is already working based on the Job No_ field.

```
select  jle.[Job No_], sum(jle.[Unit Price]) as 'Invoiced Amount', sum(jpl.[Total Price])as 'Sale $'
from [Job Ledger Entry] jle join [Job Planning Line] jpl on jle.[Job No_] = jpl.[Job No_]
where   jle.[Job No_] = 'j-2397'
group by    jle. [Job No_]
```

Comment: Is the Unit Price the same for all entries in [Job Ledger Entry] of the same Job #?  If so, you could use AVG instead of SUM.  The other option is to use MIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
select  jpl.[Job No_], SUM(jle.[Unit Price]) as 'Invoiced Amount', MIN(jpl.[Total Price]) AS 'Sale $'
from [Job Planning Line] jpl INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [Job No_], [Unit Price] FROM [Job LEdger Entry]) AS jle on jle.[Job No_] = jpl.[Job No_]
where   jpl.[Job No_] = 'j-2397'
group by    jpl. [Job No_]
```